# Save button: how to update another table with results?

Tags: php, sql, save

I have a table of recipes and there is a save button next to each recipe. When this is clicked, I would like the recipe name to be retrieved and saved to the user's profile (add to database).

However, I am encountering some problems. I have a save button and this is linked to 'save_recipe.php'. Currently when I select save, I am being directed to a blank page. I have a feeling it is something to do with the way I have created the save button, as no echo statements are being displayed.

The code for the button is:

```
<html>
<body>

  <form action="../user profile/save_recipe.php" method="post">
   <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn" value="Save Recipe"></td>
 </form> 

</body>   
</html>
```

The code for save_recipe is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>BMI Result</title>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css" type="text/css" />
<body>
    <?php

    error_reporting(E_ALL &~ E_NOTICE);

    // Start the session
    session_start();

        // If the session vars aren't set, try to set them with a cookie
    if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
        if (isset($_COOKIE['user_id']) && isset($_COOKIE['username'])) {
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $_COOKIE['user_id'];
            $_SESSION['username'] = $_COOKIE['username'];
        }
    }
    echo gfgfg;


    // Make sure the browser is transmitting in UTF-8
    header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

        // Clear the error message
    $error_msg = "";

    //if (isset($_SESSION['user_id']))
    //  echo $_SESSION['user_id'];

    $dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'help_me_be_healthy') or die("Error " . mysqli_error($dbc));
    mysqli_set_charset($dbc, "utf8");

    echo gfdgfdg;

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $recipe_name = mysqli_result(mysqli_query("SELECT `recipe_1_name`, `recipe_2_name` FROM `carbohydrates`");

                  //"SELECT `recipe_1_name` OR `recipe_2_name` FROM `carbohydrates` WHERE `user_id` = '" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "'";
            $query = "UPDATE `users` SET `recipes_saved` = $recipe_name WHERE `user_id` = '" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "'";
            $data= mysqli_query($dbc,$query);

            echo '$recipe_name';
            );

    }
    ?>
```

Any advice would be much appreciated, I'm fairly new to this!

Comment: Firstly, this will throw an error `echo gfgfg;` so please don't use pseudo-code, if that's the case. Second, use `echo $recipe_name;` without quotes. 3rd, you're not echoing your [**query**](http://us2.php.net/mysqli_query) correctly. You need to use a `while` or `foreach` condition and fetch.

Comment: ...4th there's no field in the form other than the `submit` button, 5th a cookie is pointlessly duplicated in `$_SESSION`, 6th the `SELECT` query seems pointless to...

Comment: ... and the beat goes on ♫ ;-)

Comment: Try using this where your `echo '$recipe_name';` is `foreach($data as $row) { echo $row['recipes_saved']; }` or whatever row/column you wish to use. That's but "one" way of doing it.

Comment: thanks guys, i'm actually thinking why I set it up as two different pages of code and am going to combine them. So, I'll have the page where the table of recipes is displayed in addition to the save method

Comment: You probably could make use of [`multi_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) @SarahAl

Comment: I have changed the button code to this: <html>
<body>

  <form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post"> 
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Recipe"> 
  </form>

</body>   
</html>

Comment: now going to add php code above it

Comment: Still confused about how to do this: here is what I want to: I have a table that is populated with data using PHP. I would like to retrieve the data from one column in this table and use it to update another table in the database. I have been looking around but haven't found anything that can help...

Comment: Is PHP the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'help_me_be_healthy') or die("Error " . )

You have several instances of mysqli_connect. It should be mysql_connect. Plus you really shouldn't be using root as the u-name & p-word. That's the default installation of PHP IIRC.

Comment: I have used this connection line in all other code and it works fine

Comment: Yeah, fair enough. I'm more of an ASP/MVC person. Point #2 is still valid.

Comment: ***"It should be mysql_connect"*** - um, no. `MySQL_` is deprecated, plus `localhost', 'root', 'root'` is only an example that people use in order to hide their actual DB credentials. @ryanbutler